# Python factorial sum that shows math

Tags: math, factorial

This is the code I have so far works fine but when it prints it just shows the answer rather then the full equation when I want it to print the full equation

```
    number=int(input("enter a number a number between 1 and 20"))
    def factorial(number):
      value=1
for i in range(1,number+1):
    value*=i
print("the factorial sum for", number, "is {0:,}".format(value,i))
return
```

################################

```
  if number == 0:
    print ("please select a differnt number")
  elif number > 20:
    print("please enter a number between 1 and 20")
 else:
    factorial(number)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, how can we help? How to get the actual "321" part of the output string? You may want to edit your question with that clarification, so we can help you better.

Comment: yes, I would want the output to be entire factorial equation

Comment: What do you mean?  Like this?   6! = 1*2*3*4*5*6?  Your print statement isn't inside the loop.

Comment: What do you call a factorial sum ??

Answer (score 0):

To print the whole equation you can write something like

```
f = 1
s = ''

for i in range(1, n+1):
    f *= i
    s += str(i) + '*' 

print(s[:-1], '=', f)
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the code, I added an explanation for each step. There may be some new things in here you are unfamiliar with, but exposure to it is good. Use google aggressively

```
number = 0
while True: ## this loop will catch any non-ints/float numbers inputted
    try: #test the number
        numberinput = int(input("enter a number a number between 1 and 19: "))  #user enters #
        assert numberinput > 0  #make sure the number is between your limits
        assert numberinput < 20 #make sure the number is between your limits
        number = numberinput  #set the number == to our vetted numberInput
        break #exit infinite loop
    except:  #if any errors in above, we enter this clause
        print('Please enter a valid number between 1 and 19') #tell user to try another number
        continue #continue sends us to the top of the loop (starting with try)


def factorial(number):
    value=1  #initial value
    stringOfCalculations= ''  #empty string that we can build on as we loop through
    for i in range(1, number + 1): 
        value *= i 
        if i == 1:  #if the value is 1, we dont want to do * i in the string, we want to just add i to the string since we start with 1
            stringOfCalculations += f'{i}' #we add i to the start of the string. This is called an f' string, similar to .format() but cleaner
        else: #if the number is not 1
            stringOfCalculations += f' * {i}' # we want to add * i, since were doing math these steps that aren't 1*1

    stringOfCalculations += f' = {value}' # after looping, our value is the total, so we append '= value' to our string
    print(stringOfCalculations) # print the full string
    return #you chose to return nothing here, but you could also return the value


factorial(number) #no need for the if clause since we check the number is between 1-19 in the try block
```

Comment: Consider using the `join()` function. `'*'.join(map(str,range(1,number+1`)))` for example. You may be unfamiliar with it but it's good to be exposed to it.

Comment: This type of answer is advanced, the user is new to coding and this type of response would be useless to them

Comment: I'll leave it in the comments. Answers are not solely for the questioner, they're also for everyone the finds the question later.